# @mdi/js doesn´t work on Laravel 9 Vuetify 3

Tags: laravel, icons, vuetify.js, mdi

I want to use `@mdi/js` in my Laravel 9 Vuetify 3 app. The Vuetify 3 [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/) says what should be done. But that doesn't work for me.

My app.js

```
import './bootstrap';
import '../css/app.css';

import { createApp, h } from 'vue';
import { createInertiaApp } from '@inertiajs/inertia-vue3';
import { InertiaProgress } from '@inertiajs/progress';
import { resolvePageComponent } from 'laravel-vite-plugin/inertia-helpers';
import { ZiggyVue } from '../../vendor/tightenco/ziggy/dist/vue.m';

const appName = window.document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0]?.innerText || 'Laravel';

// Vuetify
import 'vuetify/styles'
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
})

createInertiaApp({
    title: (title) => `${title} - ${appName}`,
    resolve: (name) => resolvePageComponent(`./Pages/${name}.vue`, import.meta.glob('./Pages/**/*.vue')),
    setup({ el, app, props, plugin }) {
        return createApp({ render: () => h(app, props) })
            .use(plugin)
            .use(ZiggyVue, Ziggy)
            .use(vuetify)
            .mount(el);
    },
});
```

My template:

```
<script setup>
    import { mdiAccount } from '@mdi/js'
</script>

<template>
    <v-icon :icon="mdiAccount"></v-icon> 
</template>
```

It seems vuetify `v-icon` can't handle the SVG graphic. Does anyone have an idea how I can use `@mdi/js` with `v-icon` and other vuetify emits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/features/icon-fonts/#material-design-icons-js-svg) states that you need to add a few things to your `createVuetify` call to make svg icons work.

Amend the call like this:

```js
import { aliases, mdi } from 'vuetify/iconsets/mdi-svg'

const vuetify = createVuetify({
  components,
  directives,
  icons: {
    defaultSet: 'mdi',
    aliases,
    sets: {
      mdi,
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Those who can read the documentation correctly have a clear advantage. -.- Thanks a lot